# Adding new field values to layer from another layer

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-joins

I have two layers that share a Unique `"ID"` field. Can I easily update the field values in one layer with the field values in the other layer using the Unique `"ID"` as the link field? As the layers also sit on top of each other I suppose I could alternatively use the *'equals'* operator in 'Join Attributes by location' but I thought using a fixed field value would be more reliable. One way seems to be to join the two layers and then to perform a field update but I thought it might be possible in one step with the right function.

I am aware that I can join the layers, but I need to get the data into the original layer itself so they can be handled separately.

Comment: The correct answer to your current question would be "yes, this is possible". I suggest you a) do some more research, since this issue was dealt with rather often, and b) show your efforts/attempts and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You can use QGIS expressions with field calculator to create a new field or updating an existing one. Use the function `get_feature()` to identify the feature on the other layer with the same `id` and the `attribute ()` function to get the value of any attribute from this other layer.

In my case, a have a polygon layer named `polygon` with an attibute named `value` and a point layer named `point`. Both share the same `id`. The copy the `value` attribute from the polygon to the point layer, I use this expression (replace `polygon`, `id` and `value` with the names of your layer and attributes):

```
attribute( 
    get_feature( 
        'polygon', 
        'id', 
        "id"
    ),
    'value'
)
```

[image]