# How to get the value from one field into another using a common ID Field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression

I have two layers, one being a manhole layer and the other a gravity main layer. I need to get the asset number from the manhole layer into the gravity main layer. On the gravity main layer I have a field "From_Manho" which contains an ID, that same ID exists on the manhole layer under the name "Facility_I". In my head, I'm thinking I can make an expression using the ID fields to extract the associated asset number. I came across this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394315/adding-new-field-values-to-layer-from-another-layer#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20QGIS%20expressions,attribute%20from%20this%20other%20layer.) but I wasn't able to get it to work.

This was my attempt at the expression:

```
attribute(
    get_feature(
        'ssManhole_642cc259_988d_404e_9458_9e5dc4f7b7b6', 
        Facility_I,  
        "From_Manho"
    ), 
    'Asset'
)
```

Comment: Could you instead just do a join on the ID fields and then use the calculator to copy the asset number into a field of the gravity layer?

Comment: Have a read of https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that this is a natural use case for an table join.  That said, you can implement it using a field calculator expression.  The overall structure of the OP code looks good, it looks like quotes are missing for the `Facility_I` field name in `get_feature()` function:

```
attribute(
  get_feature(
    'ssManhole_642cc259_988d_404e_9458_9e5dc4f7b7b6',
    'Facility_I',
    "From_Manho"
  ),
  'Asset'
)
```

The OP code can also be rewritten to explicitly retrieve the manhole instead of relying on implicit retrieval using double quotes:

```
attribute(
  get_feature(
    'ssManhole_642cc259_988d_404e_9458_9e5dc4f7b7b6',
    'Facility_I',
    attribute(
       'From_Manho'
    )
  ),
  'Asset'
)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the help but it still didn't work. I was trying to avoid using table join as i was hoping to make it a default value. it's looking like table join is going to be the way to go.

Comment: @Mow, what exactly isn't working?  Any specific error(s)?  I tested it on some mocked up data, and the general approach worked.  Are both layers loaded into the same project?  Is the manhole table really named with that GUID-like suffix?

Comment: There are no errors it just doesn't return any results. Yes it is named with that GUID-like suffix. I went to the map layers tab in the expression builder and selected the manholes layer.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.28.2.  I updated my answer to add a code sample that removes implicit attribute retrieval and replaces it with a call to `attribute` function.  Also, the comparison between the field in the two tables will have to be identical, so could there be a capitalization or empty space issue (assuming comparing strings)?

Comment: Is the field you are calculating the right type? If you accidentally created an Integer field but are trying to populate it with Strings then you will get null values.